# Hibernate annotation - inheritance clarification

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I have few questions on hibernate with inheritance (single table),
Can the foreign key be on the abstract class? - what if one of the child not using it?
Should vehicle members be protected?
Please share any other thoughts!

Here is an example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicles")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Vehicle {

@Id
@Column(name = "plate" ,nullable = false)
private String plate;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<EmissionInspection> insepections = new ArrayList<EmissionInspection>();

public List<EmissionInspection> getInsepections() {
    return insepections;
}

...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("POST_OFFICE_TRUCK")
@Table(name = "truck")
public class PSTruck extends Vehicle {

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TRUCK")
@Table(name = "truck")
public class Truck extends Vehicle {

    private insuranceDate;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("PRIVATE_CAR")
@Table(name = "truck")
public class PrivateCar extends Vehicle {

    private insuranceDate;      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Can the foreign key be on the abstract class?"** -> yes

**"if one of the child not using it?"** -> then it is nullreference there

**"Should vehicle members be protected? "** -> if you have public getter/setter *no*, otherwise if you need to get/set without a public get/set then *yes*

the tablename of the abstract class and the other classes are different. Normally the inheriting classes don't have any `@Table` annotation